# Does the TITAN Graph database provide a HTTP API?

Tags: http, graph-databases, titan

Is it possible to execute transactions to the TITAN
Graph database using HTTP queries sending jsons or similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Titan supports an HTTP API through Apache TinkerPop's [Gremlin Server](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_connecting_via_rest).